# Android phone HDD/SSD 2.5"/1.8" - how much power is too much?

Tags: hardware, usb-on-the-go, usb-mass-storage

Recently I started experimenting with OTG adapter and some USB devices. While pendrives, RS232 adapters etc typicially work, storage is more interesting topic. I tried to connect my 1tb Seagate SSHD but it started emitting weird beeping noise and phone didn't detect it. However today I connected my friend's Samsung T3 1TB SSD and it does work just fine. So the question is - what power draw is too much and is it possible to connect some lower power 1.8" HDD do phone? (Because high capacity SSDs are quite expensive)

It's interesting topic as vision of being able to access 1TB or even more of data on the go (without additional power) sounds quite promising. Especially for phones without sd card but also because such insane capacity cards are insanely expensive, even comparing to SSDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB flash drives consume about 1-2 watts, SSDs max 5 watts and good HDDs 6.5-7 watts. I doubt a low powered USB connection could power an HDD. Perhaps a portable HDD since those use a bit less power.

Sources: 
http://www.buildcomputers.net/power-consumption-of-pc-components.html

http://techreport.com/review/25391/wd-red-4tb-hard-drive-reviewed/3

https://superuser.com/questions/565653/how-much-power-does-a-hard-drive-use

http://www.anandtech.com/show/8747/samsung-ssd-850-evo-review/10

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power

http://www.anandtech.com/show/10163/usb-flash-drives-power-consumption-measurement-using-plugables-usbctkey

Comment: I would but it is a bunch of boring crap I thought no one would bother reading. I'll edit to cite sources.